# How to modify Pagination in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to create a report which will show pagination as per the format of the output report. If I create PDF report then I need pagination otherwise I want to hide the pagination. Is there any option that could allow me to do so??

Thanks!!

Comment: You can do it with help of JR API. You can set [JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION). You can find sample [here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/nopagebreak/index.html) and [here](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=30269). I think that it is impossible to do this in *iReport* (without programming)

Comment: Thanks Alex!. your suggestions are always helpful.. I will go through the samples from the link and will let you know if need any help..

Comment: @Alex, you can set it under Report Properties in iReport, but if you are using the same report template to export to various formats, you need to do it using the JR API.

Comment: @jschoen Do you mean that you cat set expression for *IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION* property in *iReport*? I think that you can set only constant (true or false) for this property via *iReport*

Comment: @Alex Correct, you can set it true or false in iReport. You can not use an expression to do it unfortunately. That is why you have to use the API. Also this entire conversation is because I apparently have a reading comprehension problem and thought you wrote `possible` instead of `impossible` in your first comment.